# My code works outside the function but not inside

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, global-variables

The function below is not working anymore :

```
def videos_to_watch(section): #OK 
    global list_already_watched   
    list_already_watched = already_watched(ID).tolist()
    if section == 111:
        list_to_watch = set(p111)-set(list_already_watched)
    elif section == 113:
        list_to_watch = set(p113)-set(list_already_watched)
    return list(list_to_watch)
```

When I debuged it, it said that `list_already_watched` was empty, but when I ran it outside the function, it showed the value that is registred in the dataframe. I tried to use `global` but I think I'm not using it in the right way. Could someone help me?

Comment: You may need use `global already_watched`?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will help, but maybe you should initialize the variable as well.
Like so:

```
def videos_to_watch(section): #OK 
    global list_already_watched = 0  
    list_already_watched = already_watched(ID).tolist()
    if section == 111:
        list_to_watch = set(p111)-set(list_already_watched)
    elif section == 113:
        list_to_watch = set(p113)-set(list_already_watched)
    return list(list_to_watch)
```

Comment: By doing that am I not saying that will never be a watched video? Because everytime i registred it in the dataframe it will become empty as I call the videos_to_watch function

Comment: it just wouldn't make a difference because in the next line you assign that variable to something else, so it doesn't care if it was `0` or not before.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).